AppArmor message spam about Discord snap in my kernel ring buffer
So I was trying to debug some stuff, and noticed that my snap installation of Discord seems to fill my kernel ring buffer with the same request which is being "DENIED" by the AppArmor.
Message in question:
[ 1044.201470] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44954): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201478] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44955): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201491] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44956): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201499] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44957): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201514] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44958): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201522] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44959): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[ 1044.201535] audit: type=1400 audit(1732616387.440:44960): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=5626 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

(the spam is at a point where its very difficult to find any message which isn't this one...)
I was wondering if people know what might cause this, and if this is harmful behaviour I should seek to fix (my machine has been a bit unstable, but I'm still unsure if that's a hardware or a software issue...)

This is not a problem of stability of your computer.
These kernel messages mean that AppArmor is denying the Discord snap app to use the ptrace call.
From snapcrafters' bugtracker about Discord:

Discord has a "feature" where it automatically tells all your Discord friends what game you're playing, with a "Playing World of Warcraft" (or whatever game) below your name on your friend's Discord panel(s).
Discord implements this feature by doing a scan, once every five seconds, of every numeric entry in the /proc file system. Let's say your current Linux user id is "joe", and one (of hundreds) of processes you are running is process pid == 999. Then Discord will first stat "/proc/999", and if that proc directory is owned by yourself, "joe", it will then further try to "open /proc/999/cmdline" and " readlink /proc/999/exe", in an effort to see if you're also running a recognized game executable. If (for example) it sees that you're running a World of Warcraft executable, it will tell your connected friend's Discords to add the "Playing ..." annotation below your name "Joe" on their Discord. The above stat of "/proc/999" call does not generate an error (when run by Discord inside a snap sandbox), but the additional two "open /proc/999/cmd" and "readlink /proc/999/exe" do generate EACCES (Permission denied) errors.If the only entries that Discord found matching the pattern "/proc/NNN", for some decimal number NNN, were not owned by the current Discord user, then I imagine that Discord would quietly decide that you're not running any recognized games and go on about its other business, until the next five second loop.

If you want to allow this invasive behavior from Discord, do
snap connect discord:system-observe :system-observe

(solution taken from the same GitHub site; I haven't tried it)

Aaah, that makes sense, thanks,
I thought I had disabled most of that, but seemingly not, I disabled some other things, and hope that that stops discord from sending those calls, cause its flooding my ring buffer which is kind of a problem...
Otherwise I might just give it access, as I don't care too much, though it would kindof suck if those are my only two options :/

okay, it seems that there is still no good way to suppress them (which doesn't break at discord updates), so I guess I'll just give them access, though it sucks that's the only possible way to do it :/
